# Spring Cloud @RefreshScope behind the scenes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-actuator

I have a spring boot application in which I want to use the @RefreshScope capability in order to reload external configuration in runtime, without having to restart the service.

I'm quite puzzled by a specific potential pitfall of this approach - what happens if I refresh a bean (using the endpoint exposed by the actuator) while the bean is actually performing a long-running job?

Will it:

1. Interrupt the running bean immediately (which may cause problems if my code isn't prepared for this)?
2. Gracefully wait for the bean to finish its execution before re-initializing it?
3. Something else?

I couldn't find any clear answer to this question online, including the documentation.

Comment: 2 things happen, the environment is refreshed and configuration properties beans are updated and also, beans are destroyed and the refresh scope cache is cleared. Beans are recreated on next access. If you have a bean doing something long running, I would suggest not having it be refresh scope. When the environment is refreshed a `EnvironmentChangeEvent` application event is published with which properties changed. I would listen for that and do work based on if the properties that bean is interested in changed.

Comment: @spencergibb So according to you, the beans are destroyed abruptly and not gracefully? There's no interrupt sent to them?

Comment: @KidCrippler Hello there! Did you find any answers? I faced same issues and now trying to find any information about "how to avoid destroying beans after refresh".
Many thanks for your answer!